# Radiometric corrections with R

Tags: r, landsat

I try to convert Landsat 8 files to reflectance via R / RStoolbox

I use that script :

```
metaData  <- readMeta("LC08_L1TP_183033_20210623_20210630_02_T1_MTL.txt", raw=T)
lsat <- stackMeta("LC08_L1TP_183033_20210623_20210630_02_T1_MTL.txt")
lsat_sref <- radCor(lsat, metaData, method = "dos")
```

I've got this error after `stackMeta` function:

```
Error in CRS(paste0(c("+proj=", "+zone=", "+units=m +datum="), pars, collapse = " ")) :
  No spaces permitted in PROJ4 argument-value pairs: +proj= +zone= +units=m +datum=
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Not sure we can do much beyond guesswork without a copy of that metadata file. Can you point us to a download location or share it?

Comment: sure, you can find the mtd file here : https://we.tl/t-LkAUPCLF58

Comment: RStoolbox is a depreciated package (no longer on CRAN, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RStoolbox/index.html) due to spatial classes not being updated. As such, you may start running into errors at the code level and may not be producing expected results.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a very different metadata file to the ones that `readMeta` is designed to understand.

It can be read using `raw=TRUE` because it uses the same basic format of blocks of data with begin and end markers, and key=value items.

But if you compare it to the sample data file in `?readMeta` it has very different items. Yours has:

```
> d = readMeta("./LC08_L1TP_183033_20210623_20210630_02_T1_MTL.txt",raw=TRUE)
> names(d)
 [1] "PRODUCT_CONTENTS"             "IMAGE_ATTRIBUTES"            
 [3] "PROJECTION_ATTRIBUTES"        "LEVEL1_PROCESSING_RECORD"    
 [5] "LEVEL1_MIN_MAX_RADIANCE"      "LEVEL1_MIN_MAX_REFLECTANCE"  
 [7] "LEVEL1_MIN_MAX_PIXEL_VALUE"   "LEVEL1_RADIOMETRIC_RESCALING"
 [9] "LEVEL1_THERMAL_CONSTANTS"     "LEVEL1_PROJECTION_PARAMETERS"
```

Whereas the example has:

```
> mtlFile  <- system.file("external/landsat/LT52240631988227CUB02_MTL.txt", package="RStoolbox")
> mtlMeta = readMeta(mtlFile, raw=TRUE)
> names(mtlMeta)
[1] "METADATA_FILE_INFO"    "PRODUCT_METADATA"      "IMAGE_ATTRIBUTES"     
[4] "MIN_MAX_RADIANCE"      "MIN_MAX_PIXEL_VALUE"   "PRODUCT_PARAMETERS"   
[7] "RADIOMETRIC_RESCALING" "PROJECTION_PARAMETERS"
```

These names are hard-coded into `readMeta` so if the file doesn't have a `PROJECTION_PARAMETERS`, and you pass `raw=FALSE` it fails because there's no such section in your file. Yours has a `PROJECTION_ATTRIBUTES` instead, which seems to contain projection data.

There is discussion about this on the RStoolbox source code site:

https://github.com/bleutner/RStoolbox/issues/71

Comment: I found my way here Spacedman : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69538015/radiometric-corrections-with-r